# Running (simple?) nested linear model in R

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, interaction

I have a response variable Y (continuous), and I want to see if it relates to environmental variable X (continuous). But I've taken measurements of X and Y at multiple different sites (i.e., they are probably correlated).

I really want to know whether X is related to Y, but leaving off the "nested" nature of the design will inflate my P-value. So I want to see if the relationship between X and Y is consistent among my various sites. I believe I need a nested design, but I can't really figure out how to get a P-value from R.

In addition, my "levels" of X aren't the same across each site. What I really care about is if the slope of the X vs. Y graph is consistently not-zero.

I've tried this in R:

```
glm <- (Y ~ X/site)
```

But the output doesn't really give me a P-value, and I'm not sure that the division symbol actually represents the way I've nested the data. Any clues here?

Below is a plot of X vs. Y for the 9 sites I'm looking at. I want to test whether the slope of X vs. Y is non-zero (negative in this case).

[image]

Comment: You probably are looking for mixed effects models. Something like `library(lmerTest); summary(lmer(Y ~ X + (X | site), data = your.data.frame))` You should read some introduction to mixed effects models, e.g. [this one](http://www.highstat.com/book2.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You probably are looking for mixed effects models. Something like

```
library(lmerTest)
summary(lmer(Y ~ X + (X | site)`, data = your.data.frame))
```

You should read some introduction to mixed effects models, e.g. [this one](http://www.highstat.com/book2.htm)

You should also take a look at the `mixed-model` tag.

Comment: I've copied this comment by @Roland as a community wiki answer because the comment is, more or less, an answer to this question. We have a dramatic gap between answers and questions. At least part of the problem is that some questions are answered in comments: if comments which answered the question were answers instead, we would have fewer unanswered questions.